# MVC json response what kind of response is it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, response, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a strange behavior, i have 2 different methods: but all of them return JSON, like so:

```
return Json(new { success = success }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Althought one is returned through an third party functionality, however, the first one the correct one, if i investigate the response in javascript:

```
response
{...}
    [prototype]: {...}
    success: true
```

The other response however looks like this: and it is not correct:

```
response
{...}
    [prototype]: {...}
    response: "{\"success\":true}"
    responseHeaders: "Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0\r\nContent-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\nServer: Microsoft-IIS/8.0\r\nX-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.0\r\nX-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319\r\nX-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNcaWdvclxkb2N1bWVudHNcdmlzdWFsIHN0dWRpbyAyMDEyXFByb2plY3RzXERhdGluZ1dlYnNpdGVcRGF0aW5nV2Vic2l0ZVxNeVByb2ZpbGVcVXBsb2Fk?=\r\nX-Powered-By: ASP.NET\r\nDate: Sat, 01 Feb 2014 11:09:36 GMT\r\nContent-Length: 16\r\n\r\n"
    status: 200
```

This other type of response probably being altered by third party element i suppose, but isnt it json response any more?

How can i get the value from success for example, OR if I render there as string my partial view, how do i exract it, because it looks then like this:

> response: "{\"partial\":\"\r\n\u003cli
>   id=\\"50\\"\u003e\u003cimg class=\\"cloudzoom-gallery\\"
>   src=\u0027/controller/GetThumbnail/50\u0027 data-cloudzoom
>   =\\"useZoom: \u0027.cloudzoom\u0027, image: \u0027/controller/GetImage/50\u0027,  zoomImage:
>   \u0027/MyProfile/GetLargeImage/50\u0027\\"\u003e\r\n
>   \u003cdiv class=\\"caption text-center\\"
>   style=\\"display:none;\\"\u003e\r\n
>   \u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\r\n        \u003cp\u003e
>   \r\n        \u003c/p\u003e\r\n
>   \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\u003c/li\u003e\r\n\"}"

Which is then definetly cannot be parces as a correct html :(

Any idea what does this response mean? and what type is it and how to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

```
response = response.replace(/\\"/gi,'"');
```

would do the trick as the only thing that looks invalid in your HTML is the `\"` everywhere

you could cleanup carriage returns as well if you don't need it to be present in the html partial with

```
response = response.replace(/\\"/gi,'"').replace(/[\n\r]+/g, '');
```